# Creating Uri from user input

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, browser, uri

So, I want to create an Uri from user input.
I have a textbox, an Ok button and web browser control.

User writes his desired web address, clicks button and launches getUri method.

I tried to create something like this:

```
private void ok_tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Uri address = new Uri(AdressBox.Text, UriKind.Absolute);
    web.Navigate(address);
}
```

Aaand it works quite allright. However, only when user types adress with "http://". Problem is: no one writes whole links, and with just "google.com" app crashes.

i could check if there is something like "http" in user input and add it manually... but it feels like I try to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`UriBuilder` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx). Its String constructor defaults to `HTTP` protocol:

```
private void ok_tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Uri address = new UriBuilder(AdressBox.Text).Uri;
    web.Navigate(address);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of a URI is the protocol to be used so you need to do something when it is not given by the user. Your idea for validation seems appropriate, try "http://" if nothing else is given. You might add ".com,.org,.net" too if there is no domain suffix. That's not reinventing the wheel, that's just using a circle where needed. At any rate, you should prevent app crash on imperfect user input.